# sine with fixed point input

Tags: numerical, fixed-point, trigonometry

I would like to know if there exists an implementation of the sine/cosine function that takes a fixed point input. I would prefer such an implementation for error reduction purposes. A simple version might take an N-bit unsigned integer k as input and calculate sin(2*pi*k/2^N). Does anything like this exist? If so, I would use it all the time.

Comment: To do fixed point calculations, you have to specify two things: the number of bits of scaling (how many binary bits past the binary point), and the number of integer bits.  Short answer is yes -- you could also write one yourself quite easily.

Comment: CORDIC algorithms offer a nice fixed point solutions.  Check wiki.

Answer (score 0):

I did a 16.16 fixed point sine implementation, you can find it here:
https://code.google.com/p/libfixmath/source/browse/trunk/libfixmath/fix16_trig.c#47